# Blade Template with comment on top not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**file: app/route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

**file: app/views/home.blade.php**

```
{{-- Blade comment. --}}
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('head')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="second.css" />
@stop

@section('body')
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Hello Home!</p>
@stop
```

**file: app/views/layouts/base.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    @section('head')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    @show
</head>
<body>
    @yield('body')
</body>
</html>
```

When I access to laravel.localhost/
It only output
@extends('layouts.base')

but however, if I remove the

> {{-- Blade comment. --}}

then it works perfectly.

May I know what is the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line in your extended blade view must be the @extends directive.

Comment: it means I can't add any comment on top on the file?

Comment: In this case as far as I know you can't, the @extends directive must be at the very top and then you can write your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a convention by the devs.
Look at [BladeCompiler.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php#L119) on line `119`.

```
protected function compileExtends($value)
    {
        // By convention, Blade views using template inheritance must begin with the
        // @extends expression, otherwise they will not be compiled with template
        // inheritance. So, if they do not start with that we will just return.
        if (strpos($value, '@extends') !== 0)
        {
            return $value;
        }
```